# Use OG meta tags for specific Facebook share

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, share, meta-tags

Can I specify which share I want meta tags to use on? So I have 2 shares on site one that shares the whole page and one that shares specific product. so I have meta tags for main page share.Now I want meta tags for product share and i dont know how to make it so that it knows which meta tags to use. sorry if the question is badly explained if something ask me. I have all the tags in commonlayout view inside head tags.
thanks

Comment: You need to provide a second, unique URL, that returns this different set of meta tags. You can not have multiple sets for the same URL.

Comment: @misorude can you explain in detail please?

Comment: Explain what exactly? Facebook does not allow to change any of those values dynamically any more at the time of sharing. So if you want to share two different looking things, you need two different sets of meta tags. And that means, you need to different URLs to begin with.

Comment: @misorude Yeah I got that so I need to have 2 sets of meta. where do I put url in meta?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you talking about `og:url`? Well that must contain the respective URL in each case.

Comment: @misorude so I have meta <meta property="og:url" content="window.fbSheareUrl"/> after if I write other metas titles and etc it will detect for this url?

Comment: What do you mean, “detect”? Who is supposed to detect what, when & where?

Comment: detect that this meta tags are for that url share. like I have 2 shares right. I have metas on share of the main page so I write <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.oppa.ge"/> and then like og:title, og:url etc. then I have a share for specific product I write another sets of metas with url <meta property="og:url" content="window.fbSheareUrl"/> and then  <meta property="og:title" content="OPPA - " + @detailViewModel.Name /> <meta property=og:description and etc did I get it right?

Comment: `window.fbSheareUrl` sounds like a client-side JavaScript variable? That is useless here, Facebook requests the meta tags from your server, there is no client that would care for any JS involved at this point.